# Blazor Fails to Connect to Server When Component Parameter is Too Big

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm running a .NET 6 MVC app with a few Blazor components. All of them work fine, except one.

In a view, I embed the problematic component like so, passing in two parameters, Students and IsUserPartner.

```
<component 
    type="typeof(IndexRoster)" 
    render-mode="ServerPrerendered" 
    param-Students="@Model.Students" 
    param-IsUserPartner="@User.IsInRole("Partner")" 
/>
```

The component seems to render fine initially, but after a second or two the app disconnects and the page displays the message, *"Attempting to reconnect to the server..."*.

I figured out that it's the Students parameter that's the culprit, because when I remove it, the app works fine. This parameter is a List of DTOs:

```
public class StudentIndexDTO {
    public List<StudentDisplayDTO> Students { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

What's **most interesting** is that substantially limiting the amount of items in the Students List with `param-Students="@Model.Students.GetRange(0, 10)"`, also fixes the issue. So, it seems that it's not a problem with the List per se, but rather with its size. Unfortunately, I can't limit the amount of items fetched from the Student List; the app needs to display all of them (400 - 1,000).

The only other solution I was able to come up with is setting the render mode to `Static`, but again, that's not an adequate solution since it removes other necessary functionalities.

So, how can I pass the full List to my component without causing the app to disconnect?

Comment: Have you looked into [Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: Passing the data this way is not very efficient (and you seem to have hit on a size limit) - could you fetch the data from "inside" the component instead?

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for the recommendation. I tried it, but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. I get the loading issue even if I clear the IndexRoster component of any HTML. So, it's not a problem of rendering too many elements on the page; it's strictly a problem of passing a large parameter to the component.

Comment: I see, in that case, the suggestion from @MisterMagoo sounds like the best way to go.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thank you for the suggestion. I tried populating the Students List using an async call from Blazor to a backend Controller in `OnInitializedAsync`, and it seems to be working fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a workaround thanks to the suggestion of @MisterMagoo. In the Blazor component, within `OnInitializedAsync()`, I made an async request to a backend Controller Action using `HttpClient`, which then populates the Students List with the response.